# Why android 7 local storage is smaller than the android version before?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I tried to test the size of local storage on android 7, why the limit is very small only 2.49 M, much different with android 6 has a larger that is 4.98 M? Please, I need answer for this backwardness?

Reference: http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/
[image]

Update: 2017-06-24

Comment: Without more information on the actual test conditions this is difficult to tell. It could be as simple as with Android 6 they were testing with a Nexus device with plenty of storage and for 7 they are testing on a device with half the storage meaning Chrome is more aggressive on giving space out. This test site should be used as a guidelinish-type thing and not used to set expectations.